# Android Studio - Java how to take photo(camera)

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to know how to open camera, take picture and also I want use this picture to send it. Similar like in Snapchat, I want take photo and then send it to some users which I have on Parse. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably write some code? However, sarcasm aside this is not an appropriate question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) out. It explains it clearly.